# "Que de" : analyse morphosyntaxique

Tags: grammaire, déterminants

Quelle est la partie du discours de la séquence "que de" dans : *Que de choses dans cette chambre !*

Il me semble que "que de" est ici un déterminant composé, comme *beaucoup de*, *tant de*, etc. (Riegel et al. *Grammaire méthodique du français*, p. 306).

Mais je ne suis pas sûr, car je n'ai trouvé dans aucune ressource (TLFI, Wiktionnaire, etc.) cette séquence *que de*.

**Références**

Riegel, M., Pellat, J.-C., Rioul, R. (2016/1994). *Grammaire méthodique du français*. Paris : PUF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Que de* a un rôle de déterminant exclamatif. Son sens est similaire à celui de *combien de* (quantité).

> *Ô Liberté, **que de crimes** on commet en ton nom !* (Attribué à [Manon Rolland](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manon_Roland) / vraisemblablement de Lamartine)

> ***Que d'eau, que d'eau** !* ([Mac-Mahon](https://www.histoire-en-citations.fr/citations/mac-mahon-que-d-eau-que-d-eau))

Le bon usage :

> Le déterminant exclamatif s'emploie quand on exprime un sentiment vif (admiration, étonnement, indignation, etc.) à propos de la
> réalité désignée par le nom que détermine l'exclamatif.

Comment: *que de* est un déterminant composé, avec rôle de déterminant exclamatif ?

Comment: C'est bien comme ça que je l'analyse.

Comment: Merci pour l'inévitable citation de ce bon vieux Mac-Mahon!